# Eventos en Java con botones

Tags: java

Tengo una duda con mi código, el problema es que al momento de añadir el precio a cambiar, me lanza la excepción de tipo NullPointerException. Entonces no se sí deba cambiar mi bloque try-catch. ¿Cómo podría resolverlo?

```java
private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
            cad = dulcs.leerArchivo();
            cad = tools.validacionS( cad +"Ingrese el nombre del producto: " );
            int cantidad = tools.validacionI( "Ingrese la cantidad disponible del producto: " );
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(VentanaAdmin.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            if( admin.cambiarCantidad( cad , cantidad, dulcs.getDulces() ) == true )
            {
                tools.msj( "!Operación exitosa!" );
            }
            else
            {
                tools.msj( "Error ahorita vemos que pedo: ");
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(VentanaAdmin.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Como consejo procura agregar siempre el código como texto ya que algunos usuarios pueden tener problema para visualizar el código en la imagen.

Comment: Por favor no modifiques tu pregunta, agrega ediciones de otra forma las respuestas que agreguemos ya no aplicarán. Revisa si dulcs tiene valor null, eso puede ser el problema.

Comment: ¿En qué linea de código te lanza el NullPointerException? Verifica que tus objetos estén inicializados antes de ocuparlos

Comment: @FernandoOxyde precisamente en esta línea "cad = tools.validacionS( cad +"Ingrese el nombre del producto: " );"

Comment: Checa que tu objeto ´tools´ se haya instanciado correctamente como ´Tools tools = new Tools();´ e inicializado no sé si ocupas algún constructor

Comment: "tools" sí está bien inicializado y no ocupo constructor, de hecho lo que le mando al método validaciónS son dos archivos (cad) seguido del nombre del producto a buscar. Entonces no se que sea :(

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas cambiar el bloque, actualmente solo estas "atrapando" un error del tipo `ClassNotFoundException`, debes definir un error del tipo `NullPointerException` si deseas capturar este tipo de error:

```
   try{

        ...
        ...

    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Agregué lo que mencionó, ahora me muestra "null" en la terminal, sin embargo en mi método no cambia nada, es decir, no modifica la cantidad de mi producto.